# Parsing JSON com volley android

Tags: android, json, android-studio, volley

Tenho este JSON no lado do servidor:

```
[{"idreg":"271896",
"code":"USD",
"codein":"BRL",
"name":"D\u00f3lar Comercial",
"high":"3.2652",
"pctChange":"-0.939",
"open":"0",
"bid":"3.2492",
"ask":"3.2497"}]
```

Quero usar o valor do "ask" mas não sei exatamente como interpretalo

Aqui está meu código:

```
JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new 

Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject("ask");


            }
           JSONcatch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },null);
```

Desse jeito ele não me retorna o valor, o que devo fazer para corrigir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, caso observe existe um "[ ]" antes e depois do retorno, isso significa que o JSON é um Array, por isso, o que precisas fazer (e provavelmente irá resolver seu problema), é mudar de JSONObject para array, e depois pegar o JSONObject

```
JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new 

Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(0);
            Double ask = obj.getDouble("ask");
        }
       JSONcatch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
},null);
```